# Recover ZFS mirror from pool with unavailable device

Tags: linux, ubuntu, zfs, data-recovery

I tried to expand my two-way mirror to a three-way mirror. The new drive had some filesystem issues (ext4) so I tried to force `zpool add -f` the drive for ZFS to handle for me. This led to a weird configuration:

```
 config:
    mypool                ONLINE
      mirror-0            ONLINE
        wwn-drive1-part1  ONLINE
        wwn-drive2-part1  ONLINE
      scsi-new-drive      ONLINE
```

So I then tried to attach the new drive:

```
sudo zpool attach -f mypool wwn-drive1-part1 scsi-new-drive 
/dev/disk/by-id/scsi-new-drive is in use and contains a unknown filesystem.
```

What I then did which further complicated things is export the pool and wipe the drive (`wipefs -a`). Now of course when I try to import the pool I get:

```
 config:

    mypool                    UNAVAIL  insufficient replicas
      mirror-0                ONLINE
        wwn-drive1-part1      ONLINE
        wwn-drive1-part1      ONLINE
      scsi-new-drive          UNAVAIL
```

The existing mirror has two 10TB drives with about 6TB used. I have backups but if possible, I'd like to avoid them and recover (or move?) the pool. I want to get to this state:

```
    mypool
      mirror-0
        wwn-drive1-part1
        wwn-drive1-part1
        new-drive
```

Is there any hope? What can I do to restore the pool to operational?

Comment: recover is faster imho due the manipulation

Comment: which zfs version are you using (you can find it via `modinfo zfs | head`)?

Comment: @shodanshok I am on version `2.1.5-1ubuntu6~22.04.1` however the pool was created with an older version, a few years back.

Answer (score 2):

**SHORT ANSWER:** *restore from backup.* If that fails, try the suggestion below. If even that fails, contact a professional recovery service.

**LONG ANSWER:** you basically added the disk as a top level vdev (stripe member), then *wiped* some key data (ie: ZFS label) from it and corrupted your pool. Next time, to add a mirror leg (ie: going from 2-ways mirror to a 3-ways mirrors) remember to only use `zpool attach` *without* `zpool add`. When adding a disk by mistake, on recent (>= 2.x) ZFS versions you can issue `zpool remove` to remove the disk from the pool. *Never* wipe your disks without first taking the time to to really understand what you are doing.

If you can't restore from backup, try the following:

```
echo 1 > /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_max_missing_tvds
echo 1 > /sys/module/zfs/parameters/zfs_recover
zpool import -o readonly=on -o failmode=continue mypool
```

If the pool is correctly imported, you can use a snapshot done *before* adding the new disk to recover your data. If no such snapshot exists, you can try to read from the "live" filesystem, but be aware that any data written after `zfs add` will be corrupted (and accessing such data will probably suspend the pool due to IO errors, possibly blocking/crashing the machine).